# Is operational amplifier PSRR+ valid for positive output voltages and vice versa?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, psrr

The positive and negative supply rejection ratios (PSRR+, PSRR-) are usually different, sometimes the difference is more pronounced with frequency: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf?ts=1698751029003&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F, see p.18.

Is it safe to assume that if the operational amplifier's output is positive, it is PSRR+ that should be considered (and vice versa)? Or are things more complex?

What made me think of this was a situation where the positive supply is a very clean +5V, which is then used as input for a -5V charge pump to create the negative supply. So if the charge pump switching frequency is say 100kHz and the operational amplifier is an LM358B, then for positive output voltages the PSRR is 70dB and for negative output voltages the PSRR is just 25dB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with outputs; it's all about the power supply noise creating a false signal at the inputs. So, if your negative supply has 100 mV p-p of ripple at 100 kHz, the -PSRR is 23 dB as per this graph in the data sheet you linked: -

[image]

I've added the green lines btw.

The inputs will be subject to an AC noise signal of 5.62 mV p-p by my calculation. It's as simple as that for this device. I'm not considering +PSRR because it is nearly 70 dB and won't add much of a signal. If your op-amp circuit gain is (say) unity (at 100 kHz) then you will see 7.08 mV p-p on the output. If your op-amp circuit gain is higher, you will see proportionately more output noise.

Comment: I think you have calculated for 25 dB. 23 dB would give 7.08 mVp-p, I believe.

Comment: @AdamHaun you are indeed correct and, I shall correct the answer.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about the output being the PSRR mechanism. It seems it is rather the input: "The power voltage affects the bias point of the input differential pair..." (https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf, p.185). At least for DC PSRR. I have also found this now that includes the Miller capacitor: https://mixsignal.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/l180-psrr-2up.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to assume that if the operational amplifier's output is positive, it is PSRR+ that should be considered (and vice versa)? Or are things more complex?

No, it's not more complex, it's simpler.

It doesn't matter what the output voltage is.

PSRR+ is used when the noise is applied to the positive supply rail of the op-amp. PSRR- is used when the noise is applied to the negative supply rail.

Comment: Thanks. But thinking of pure DC PSRR, how would you interpret the LT1678 datasheet (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/16789fs.pdf)? The typical PSRR in the table for +/-15V is 130dB but the PSRR+ is 120dB and the PSRR- is about 125dB in the graph. The values are not so wide apart but still different. I would probably choose the worst case (120dB) if my supply was e.g. +/-14V instead.

Comment: @Hyp, if it's important to you, you'll have to call your Analog applications engineer and ask them why the graph and table aren't consistent. One guess: The table could be based on purely DC measurements, while the graph must be based on swept-frequency measurements. Possibly there are different measurement set-ups and they happen to have given slightly different results for this very sensitive measurement. In any case you should only rely on the "MIN" value in the table which is 96 dB.